# Java - Printing n times a string which is included in an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, string, object

There's an exercise I'm doing which asks the user for an integer (points) until the user input is -1. It then wants me to display the average of these points, the average of the passing points (those >50), the pass percentage, and finally the grade distribution which is the part that I'm facing the problem.

The Grade Distribution part basically awards a grade from 0 to 5, based on how many points each input is. For example, an input integer <50 points will get a 0 grade, while one >50 && <60 will get the grade 1 etc. After the user has finished submitting the points, it then calculates how many people have scored a specific grade and distributes that number as a string (stars). So say that the user submits five times the points integer 49, there will be five stars at the grade 0.
[image]

After hours of trying, I managed to solve it but probably in the most unreliable way ever. I have three java files. One for the main, one for the class Points and one for the class Grades. In the Grades class, I just have two instance variables, a string(stars) and the integer grade. In the Points class, where I calculate the averages etc, I also create a new ArrayList and through a method I call in the main program, named createFiveGrades, I add 5 seperate Grades objects. Then through the method pointsToGrade (that I again call in the main) I convert the points to grades and add stars in the objects of the aforementioned ArrayList when applicable.
The class Points:

```
public class Points {

    private int points;
    private int counter;
    private int passingPoints;
    private int passingCounter;
    private ArrayList<Grades> distr;

    public Points() {
        this.points = 0;
        this.counter = 0;
        this.passingPoints = 0;
        this.passingCounter = 0;
        this.distr = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addPoints(int points) {
   //code
    }

    public double totalPointsAverage() {
        //code
    }

    public int getPassingPoints() {
        //code
    }

    public double passingPointsAverage() {

        //code

    }

    public double passPercentage() {
        //code
    }

    public void createFiveGrades() {
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(0).setGrade(0);
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(1).setGrade(1);
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(2).setGrade(2);
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(3).setGrade(3);
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(4).setGrade(4);
        this.distr.add(new Grades());
        this.distr.get(5).setGrade(5);
    }

    public void pointsToGrade(int po) {

        if (po < 50) {
            this.distr.get(0).addStars("*");
        } else if (po >= 50 && po < 60) {
            this.distr.get(1).addStars("*");
        } else if (po >= 60 && po < 70) {
            this.distr.get(2).addStars("*");
        } else if (po >= 70 && po < 80) {
            this.distr.get(3).addStars("*");
        } else if (po >= 80 && po < 90) {
            this.distr.get(4).addStars("*");
        } else if (po >= 90 && po <= 100) {
            this.distr.get(5).addStars("*");
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Grades> distribution() {
        return this.distr;
    }
```

The class Grades:

```
public class Grades {

    private int grade;
    private String stars;

    public Grades() {
        this.grade = 0;
        this.stars = "";

    }

    public void setGrade(int n) {
        this.grade = n;
    }

    public void addStars(String str) {
        this.stars += str;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.grade + ": " + stars;
    }

}
```

The main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Points points = new Points();
        points.createFiveGrades();

        System.out.println("Enter points in totals, -1 stops:");
        while (true) {

            int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            if (input == -1) {
                System.out.println("Point average (all): " + points.totalPointsAverage());
                if (points.getPassingPoints() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Point average (passing): " + points.passingPointsAverage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Point average (passing): -");
                }
                System.out.println("Pass percentage: " + points.passPercentage());
                System.out.println("Grade distribution: ");
                for (int i=points.distribution().size()-1; i>=0;  i--) {
                    System.out.println(points.distribution().get(i));
                }
                break;
            } else if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
                points.addPoints(input);
                points.pointsToGrade(input);

            }
```

**Question:** What other ways would be better to implement the Grade Distribution feature of the program? Please do not give me the solution, but rather something to think of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom class for the grades, you could simply use a map from the grade (Integer) to the number of occurrences of this grade (Integer). Then you can build the star string only at print time based on the values stored in the map.

Comment: Thank you for replying! In this course, I haven't been taught about the map and therefore they expect me to find a way to solve it without it. Any other suggestions? Thanks again!